# What is the CDF of a linear combination of a Gamma and a Hyperbolic random variables?

Tags: random-variables, hyperbolic-functions, gamma-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am interested in the evaluation of the risk stemming from the combination of two weather events: heavy rain and low temperature. Rainfall $R$ can be modeled as a Gamma distribution, temperature $T$ as a hyperbolic one (or, alternately, as a Normal Inverse Gaussian). The resulting random variable is $$X = - \alpha R + \beta T$$. 
Rainfall and temperature are independent variables.
What is its CDF? Or how can I evaluate it numerically?

Comment: Since neither a hyperbolic distribution nor a normal-inverse Gaussian have CDFs on Wikipedia it seems unlikely that your question will have an easy answer

Comment: The quick and dirty method would be to make a large number of independent samples, say $10^6$ samples of $R$ and $T$, and then approximate $P(X\leq x)$ by the proportion of samples with $-\alpha R + \beta T \leq x$. To increase precision, simply increase the number of samples.

Comment: @leander Thank you for this suggestion. I believe that it is the simplest. An exact closed form might be impossible to establish. Regards.